# Pattern to achieve nested routes

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm new to routes and I ignore a common pattern to select two id's on same route.

I've products id and when a product is selected the user can select subproducts, services, etc on this product and then create, edit, etc.

Each Mongo document from services, subproducts, etc save the id of the product they are related to.

The way to achieve this is doing a route with 2 id: /{product_id}/{subproduct_id}/edit ? I've to do this for every route ? Then will I have to call 2 subscribes in every waitOn (product and subproduct) ?

Is there another better aproach where I can get the product collection first and then do only 1 subscribe inside waitOn for subproducts routes ? Using Sessions ?

Thanks

Comment: Does your "subproduct" know which product it belongs to? (on the database level)

Comment: Yes, each subproduct has product _id on its Mongo database document